# Override the back navigation (gestures, buttons) for certain pages in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

There are pages or page states where I would simply like to not allow the user to go back to the previous page no matter what, like for example when establishing a global connection to a device.

For disabling and hiding the back button I have found this:

```xml
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
  <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False" IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

This, however, does not disable the backward navigation gestures you can perform on Android. I want to prevent backward navigation completely, or at least to send the user to their phone's home page.

Comment: I haven't found c# doc or example. Could adapt either of these from java/kotlin: [Android doc: On BackInvokedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/OnBackInvokedCallback). [Medium post: How to Migrate the Deprecated OnBackPressed](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/how-to-migrate-the-deprecated-onbackpressed-function-e66bb29fa2fd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough first implementation of a solution I came with, that I find quite elegant and decoupled (open to suggestions or critique though):

```cs
// ShellNavigation.cs
public class ShellNavigation : INavigation, IDisposable {
    private readonly IEnumerable<Func<bool>> _navigationConditions;

    private bool CanNavigate 
    {
        get 
        {
            foreach (Func<bool> condition in _navigationConditions)
            {
                if (!condition())
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ShellNavigation(IEnumerable<Func<bool>> navigationConditions)
    {
        _navigationConditions = navigationConditions ?? Enumerable.Empty<Func<bool>>();
        Shell.Current.Navigating += OnNavigatingChanged;
    }

    // More code...

    private void OnNavigatingChanged(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CanNavigate && e.CanCancel)
        {
            e.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// DI container configuration file
private static MauiAppBuilder AddNavigation(this MauiAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Services.AddSingleton<INavigation>(p =>
    {
        var navigationConditions = new List<Func<bool>>
        {
            () => !p.GetRequiredService<IDeviceConnectionMonitor>().ConnectionState.IsTransition()
        };

        return new ShellNavigation(navigationConditions);
    });

    return app;
}
```